# Way of checking IsPostBack or IsCallBack from within a VB.NET class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, postback, callback

I need to be able to tell from within a VB.NET class (not a user control) whether or not the current request is a PostBack and/or CallBack (AJAX). In the past I've been able to get information about the request, response, session, etc through HttpContext.Current but I haven't been able to find the Page object in HttpContext.Current.

Is this possible?

Comment: @TwoBears -- True, but in a user control you have easy access to the IsPostBack variable where as in a normal class that's not a user control (e.g. MyClass.vb as opposed to MyControl.ascx.vb) you don't have as much easy access to such variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HttpContext.Current.Handler will return a System.Web.IHandler, which may happen to be a System.Web.UI.Page. Use the as operator to cast it to a Page, and be sure to check whether it's null before using it.

Answer (score 3):

Skirting how to get the Page object, have you considered merely checking if the HTTP method was "POST" in the request object?